# bokeh is not plotting my graphs after giving input

Tags: python, bokeh

After seeing the capabilities of Bokeh I started working with it. Now I am trying to make a Vbar with my dataset.

my dataset (10 rows)

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noPqd.png)

I have read the tutorial quite a number of times and used the example provided by the official documentation:

https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-ate6xt0k/notebooks/tutorial/07%20-%20Bar%20and%20Categorical%20Data%20Plots.ipynb

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(fruits=fruits, counts=counts, color=Spectral6))

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, y_range=(0, 9), title="Fruit Counts")
p.vbar(x='fruits', top='counts', width=0.9, color='color', legend="fruits", source=source)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = "top_center"

show(p)
```

This I tried to replicate with my own dataset.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6


source = ColumnDataSource(top_ten_start)

p = figure(x_range='Bank_name', plot_height=250, y_range=(0, 90), title="BAnks")
p.vbar(x='Bank_name', top='Tier_1_ratio', width=0.9, legend="test", source=source)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = "top_center"

show(p)
```

I expected to see a bar chart as shown on the tutorial but nothing is plotting.
I thought by replacing the input of the "x_range", "plot" and "x" it would be enough to work.
Perhaps the following information would help:

These are the dtypes:

```
Country_code     object
Bank_name        object
Tier_1_ratio    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: The tutorial example you based your code on shows explicitly data passed to the ColumnDataSource but your code doesn't. Please add your definition for **top_ten_start** preferably in dictionary format, like in the example (just a few lines from your dataset) ? The point is there may be some issue in the way you are reading/passing it to ColumnDataSource

Comment: Thanks for your time. The answer given below has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x_range expects a list of categorical values but you supplied a string. This would be okay if it was a glyph and you were using a source, but this is not a glyph. I changed this variable to source.data['Bank_name'] so it uses the bank names in your ColumnDataSource.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral7
import pandas as pd

top_ten_start = pd.read_csv('top_ten_start.csv')
top_ten_start['color'] = Spectral7

source = ColumnDataSource(top_ten_start)

p = figure(x_range=source.data['Bank_name'], plot_height=750, y_range=(0, 90), title="Banks")
p.vbar(x='Bank_name', top='Tier_1_ratio', width=0.9, legend='Bank_name', source=source, color='color')

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45

show(p)
```

[image: Output]